# R Shiny downloadHandler() error while downloading Shapefiles using writeogr()

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to R shiny and creating a Shiny application to convert CSV file to shapefile. While running my codes I am getting this error:

[image]

**My codes:**

```
runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
      fileInput('inputdata', 'Input file',accept=c('.csv')),
      plotOutput("xyPlot"),
      downloadButton('downloadShp', 'DownloadSHP')
       ),
  server = function(input, output) {

  output$xyPlot <-  renderPlot({

  myXY<- input$inputdata
  if (is.null(myXY)) 
    return(NULL)       

  xyPoints<-read.table(myXY$datapath, sep=",", header=T)

  SHP <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords= cbind(xyPoints[,1:2]), data =  xyPoints)
  proj4string = CRS('+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83')

  plot(SHP)

  output$downloadShp <- downloadHandler(
    filename = 'fbCrawlExport.zip',
    content = function(file) {
      if (length(Sys.glob("fbCrawl.*"))>0){
        file.remove(Sys.glob("fbCrawl.*"))
      }
      writeOGR(SHP, dsn="fbCrawl.shp", layer="fbCrawl", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
      write.csv(as.data.frame(cbind(SHP@data, as.data.frame(SHP@coords))), "fbCrawl.csv")
      zip(zipfile='fbCrawlExport.zip', files=Sys.glob("fbCrawl.*"))
      file.copy("fbCrawlExport.zip", file)
      if (length(Sys.glob("fbCrawl.*"))>0){
        file.remove(Sys.glob("fbCrawl.*"))
      }
    }
  )

  }) 
 }
 ))
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample data file?

Comment: File is similar to this with X and Y coordinates.
      x                    y
74.761725 34.6015025
74.763425 34.6014575
74.766075 34.6014425
74.764975 34.6014375
74.766725 34.6014075
74.765975 34.6013925
74.762425 34.6013875
74.766825 34.6013825
74.761575 34.6013675
74.763825 34.6013575
74.766625 34.6013525
74.764175 34.6013475
74.766925 34.6013475
74.760625 34.6013425
74.766225 34.6013375
74.765875 34.6013225
74.766225 34.6013075
74.765975 34.6013025
74.760875 34.6012625
74.761875 34.6012625
74.764725 34.6012575
74.767225 34.6012525

Comment: I am sorry could not find attach file option in comment section. Please edit my comment.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for me. Can you provide the `sessionInfo()`?

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue using Rtools.
Here is my updated code

```
require(shiny)
require(sp)
require(rgdal)
Sys.setenv("R_ZIPCMD" = "C:/Rtools/bin/zip.exe")

runApp(
  list(
ui = bootstrapPage(
  fileInput('inputdata', 'Input file',accept=c('.csv')),
  downloadButton('downloadShp', 'DownloadSHP')
),
server = function(input, output) {

  createShp <- reactive({
    myXY <- input$inputdata
    if (is.null(myXY)){
      return(NULL)      
    } else {
      xyPoints <- read.table(myXY$datapath, sep=",", header=T)

      SHP <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords= cbind(xyPoints[,1:2]), data =  xyPoints)
      proj4string(SHP) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
      return(SHP)
    }
  })

  output$downloadShp <- downloadHandler(

    filename = function() { paste0("shpExport.zip") }, #paste('shpExport.zip',
    content = function(file) {
      if (length(Sys.glob("shpExport.*"))>0){
        file.remove(Sys.glob("shpExport.*"))
      }
      writeOGR(createShp(), dsn="shpExport.shp", layer="shpExport", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
      zip(zipfile='shpExport.zip', files=Sys.glob("shpExport.*"),zip = Sys.getenv("R_ZIPCMD", "zip"))
      file.copy("shpExport.zip", file)
      if (length(Sys.glob("shpExport.*"))>0){
        file.remove(Sys.glob("shpExport.*"))
      }
    }
  )

}) 
)
```